# Can i check this box " Add anaconda3 to my path environmental variable", If i already install "python"

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables

I already install python so is there a need to check this box of " Add anaconda3 to my path environmental variable"
[Anaconda Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP9eV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already installed a Python version, it's probably on the system path and you can call Python on the command prompt.

Anaconda works differently. You first have to **activate** an environment (there is at least the `base` environment), before you can call Python. You have 2 options:

1. Call Python from the `Anaconda Prompt`
2. On the command prompt run `conda activate` before calling Python

An activated environemnt will change the command prompt to something like

```
(base) C:\
```

If you add Anaconda Python to the Path, your previous install is no longer accessible. Anaconda's Python will start, but with a limited set of packages only and e.g. no C-libraries.

There are only a few special use cases where adding Anaconda Python to the Path makes sense.